# how to use data-attribute in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, custom-data-attribute

I have a html select syntax like :

```
<select id="salary_structure_salary_structure_line_items_attributes_0_payhead_id" class="half" name="salary_structure[salary_structure_line_items_attributes][0][payhead_id]">
<option data-payhead="Earnings" value="2"> Basic </option>
<option data-payhead="Earnings" value="3"> Daily allowance </option>
<option data-payhead="Standard deductions" value="4"> Employee provident fund </option>
</select>
```

How do i get this work in rails syntax? what change should i do in below code to get the above result:

```
<%= select_tag "salary_structure[salary_structure_line_items_attributes][#{index}][payhead_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@payheads, :id, :payhead_name, :selected => salary_structure_line_item.payhead_id ), :include_blank => true, :class => "half"%>
```

also i want to use 'selected' option in this code.

Comment: `data-attributes` is not rails things it `HTML5` thing also you need to tell us what you want selecting the `selected` options from the list of options can be achieved using javascript code

Comment: @Viren hi I have used a selected option in my rails syntax, the same thing i want to use in html syntax if possible.

Comment: could you please tell us what you want to achieve with data-attributes

Comment: @Viren i want to calculate total amount but it depends on payhead type if payhead type is 'Earnings' than amount will be added to total else it will be deducted from total. That's why i want to get payhead type through data attribute and i am getting it through HTML but at the time of edit it will display first payhead by default. It should display the payhead selected not the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options_array = [
  ["Basic", 2, "data-payhead" => "Earnings"],
  ["Daily allowance", 3, "data-payhead" => "Earnings"],
  ["Standard deductions", 4, "data-payhead" => "Standard deductions"]
]

select_tag("salary_structure[salary_structure_line_items_attributes][0][payhead_id]", options_for_select(options_array, value), :class => "half")
```

In the above code, in the options_for_select method please specify the value with the select box option's value. this will embed the selected attribute for that option

Answer (score 2):

Hey I think this is rather complicated using the options from collection for select

See: http://www.redguava.com.au/2011/03/rails-3-select-list-items-with-custom-attributes/

Comment: Then why did you accept this answer ? Since you have accepted, no one else will try to answer this question